# NotFound error when calling flights date API

Tags: node.js, amadeus

I have been using [NodeJS library](https://github.com/amadeus4dev/amadeus-node) for querying the price of the chepeast flight for a route, for next 60 days. Even after switching to production environment, the API throws 404 error (details mentioned below) for some common routes like SFO to YYC.

Do let me know how I can resolve this.

```
NotFoundError {
  response: Response {
    headers: {
      date: 'Tue, 19 Oct 2021 17:09:32 GMT',
      'content-type': 'application/vnd.amadeus+json',
      'content-length': '263',
      connection: 'close',
      'ama-internal-message-version': '14.1',
      'ama-request-id': '00010UI9218IBV',
      'ama-gateway-request-id': 'rrt-0b7b1036c139b8050-a-eu-4707-50043169-1',
      'access-control-allow-headers': 'origin, x-requested-with, accept, Content-Type, Authorization',
      'access-control-max-age': '3628800',
      'access-control-allow-methods': '*',
      server: 'Amadeus',
      'access-control-allow-origin': '*'
    },
    statusCode: 404,
    request: Request {
      host: 'api.amadeus.com',
      port: 443,
      ssl: true,
      scheme: 'https',
      verb: 'GET',
      path: '/v1/shopping/flight-dates',
      params: [Object],
      queryPath: '/v1/shopping/flight-dates?origin=SFO&destination=YYC&departureDate=2021-10-19%2C2021-12-
      18&oneWay=true&viewBy=DATE',
      bearerToken: '[REDACTED]',
      clientVersion: '5.7.0',
      languageVersion: '14.16.1',
      appId: null,
      appVersion: null,
      headers: [Object]
    },
    body: '{"errors":[{"status":404,"code":6003,"title":"ITEM/DATA NOT FOUND OR DATA NOT EXISTING","detail":"No price result found"},{"status":404,"code":6003,"title" :"ITEM/DATA NOT FOUND OR DATA NOT EXISTING","detail":"No price results found for input combined criteria"}]}',
    result: { errors: [Array] },
    data: undefined,
    parsed: true
  },
  description: [
    {
      status: 404,
      code: 6003,
      title: 'ITEM/DATA NOT FOUND OR DATA NOT EXISTING',
      detail: 'No price result found'
    },
    {
      status: 404,
      code: 6003,
      title: 'ITEM/DATA NOT FOUND OR DATA NOT EXISTING',
      detail: 'No price results found for input combined criteria'
    }
  ],
  code: 'NotFoundError'
}
```

My code to query the data looks something like this:

```
const Amadeus = require("amadeus");

var client = new Amadeus({
  hostname: "production",
  clientId: FLIGHT_SEARCH_API_KEY,
  clientSecret: FLIGHT_SEARCH_API_SECRET,
});

const response = await client.shopping.flightDates.get({
  origin,
  destination,
  departureDate: `${currentDate},${lastDate}`,
  oneWay: true,
  viewBy: "DATE",
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Flight Inspiration Search & Flight Cheapest Date Search APIs are built on top of a pre-computed cache. The APIs compute every day the most trending options based on past searches and bookings and fill the cache, which means that the cache is dynamic. If you need to get access to a full inventory of Amadeus you need to use the live [Flight Offers Search API](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/flight-offers-search).

Comment: It is disappointing to see that there isn't a way to know cheapest price for a route, given a date range. Thanks for your answer though, I think the documentation should explain things in much elaborate way. With your answer I think exhausting the free API limit doesn't seem to be too far fetched now.